# How to replace add to cart button text in drupal commerce programatically?

Tags: commerce

[image]I am getting this html of add to cart button

```
<button type="submit" id="edit-submit" name="op" value="Add to cart" class="btn btn-success form-submit">Add to cart</button>
```

I am using this code in `hook_form_alter()`.

```
$form['submit']['#attributes']['title'] = $form['submit']['#attributes']['value'] = t("Applied");
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `$form['submit']` is the correct element:

```
$form['submit']['#value'] = 'New value';
```

Comment: Its changing value of input box.. not a text its return me
<button type="submit" id="edit-submit" name="op" value="New value" class="btn btn-success form-submit">Add to cart</button>